# How to make MaterialUI styles declaration debuggable?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I have the following code:

```
<Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between" />
```

Which produces this CSS declaration.

Why it is not possible to tick/untick the styles in the browser?
How to make it possible?

[image: styles declaration]

Comment: I think that is not because of material-ui but because you are probably doing hot-reload?

Comment: Yes, also the style declaration is injected into the HTML but its content is deleted: https://imgur.com/a/mj2OWr1

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19048